# Error with RandomForest in R because of "too many categories"

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to train a RF model in R, but when i try to define the model:

```
rf <- randomForest(labs ~ .,data=as.matrix(dd.train))
```

It gives me the error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

Any idea what could it be?

And no, before you say "You have some categoric variable with more than 53 categories". No, all variables but `labs` are numeric.

Tim Biegeleisen: Read the last line of my question and you will see why is not the same as the one you are linking!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Sounds like your data might not be properly encoded.

Comment: use `forcats::fct_lump()` to reduce number of factors

Comment: @jyjek The factor variable only has 26 categories.

Comment: @MrFlick Data is properly encoded; 256 `numeric` matrix columns and one `categoric` (26 levels) column (labs in this case in the formula). All triple checked for any kind of random misclass assignments. I can't -and won't- provide a "working example" since i'm using a very large data input (which is confidential btw) and the question is not in the form of "I'm in A and i don't know how to reach B". I suspect that maybe the problem is that there are too many numeric columns in the formula and it's -erroneously- outputting it as a too-many-categories error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to address followup from OP**

I believe using `as.matrix` in this case implicitly creates factors. It is also not necessary for this packages. You can keep it as a data frame, but will need to make sure that any unused factor levels are dropped by using `droplevels` (or something similar). There are many reasons an unused factor may be in your data set, but a common one is a dropped observation.

Below is a quick example that reproduces your error:

```
library('randomForest')

#making a toy data frame
x <- data.frame('one' = c(1,1,1,1,1,seq(50) ),
       'two' = c(seq(54),NA),
       'three' = seq(55),
       'four' = seq(55) )

x$one <- as.factor(x$one)

x <- na.omit(x) #getting rid of an NA. Note this removes the whole row.

randomForest(one ~., data = as.matrix(x)) #your first error
randomForest(one ~., data = x) #your second error

x <- droplevels(x)

randomForest(one ~., data = x) #OK
```

Comment: Without the matrix coercion for the `data` arg. it gives this error `Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can't have empty classes in y.`

Comment: Already tried it, not working either.. but i just realized something, when i split into the train/test subsets, in the train data there are not cases of every category of the y variable in the formula, you think that could be the problem?

Comment: I found the problem!! In the factor column there were whitespaces sometimes in the category names, and those ones, somehow; turned into NULL values (no idea why, i found out by getting a `table` of the labs column). I fixed it with a `gsub(" ",".",labs)`.

Comment: I'm gonna mark your answer as the accepted thou, since it can be a good guide for other people dealing with the same issues in rf.